# Ajax: Form not submitting after running the OnBegin function

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, form-submit

in a asp.net web application, I am using AJAX to submit a form.
I want to run a javascript code before submitting it.
So I did this:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveProductDetails", "Store", new AjaxOptions
{
HttpMethod = "Post",
LoadingElementId = "progress",
OnBegin = "BeforeSubmit()",
OnSuccess = "closeMe()",
OnFailure = "doAlert('An error occurred while trying to save your changes. Please contact your Administrator')"
}))
```

But the problem is that After running the BeforeSubmit() function the submit is stopping. the form is not submitting.

There is no problems with the BeforeSubmit() function.
If I dont do anything with the OnBegin, the form submits properly.
Any help is greatly Appreciated.

Comment: after begin your request should be Async

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like below.

View code

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "frmId", @name = "frmId" }))
    {
            @*Your code*@
            @*You have to define input as a type button not as a sumit. *@            
            <input value="Submit" type="button" id="btnSubmit" onclick="ValidateUser()" />
    }

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function ValidateUser() {
    // Do your verification here.
    $("#frmId").submit();
    }

</script>
```